# Why button style classes are not working inside tree tags in OpenERP7?

Tags: python, xml, button, odoo, openerp-7

I created a form, and in its XML definition I added a tree which is working (I can see a list of records). Each row of the tree has a button which is working too, but I am only seeing the symbol of image not found (if I open the browser's developer mode, I can check that the img tag is pointing to a picture called undefined.png).

However, if I cut the line of the button and paste it out of the field ("link_category"), I can see the button in the right way. Why?

Here is my XML:

```
<group>
    <field name="link_category" nolabel="1">
        <tree string="Categories" editable="bottom">
            <field name="active_category"/>
            <field name="link_category_id"/>
            <field name="type"/>
            <field name="date"/>
            <field name="observations"/>
            <button name="open_history" type="object" string="View history" class="oe_link"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</group>
```

**EDIT**

**link_category** is a function field:

'link_category': fields.function(_get_link_category, type='many2many', obj="res.partner.link.category", method=True, string='Categories'),

And its function is:

```
def _get_link_category(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
    result = {}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        sql_req0 = """ 
        SELECT DISTINCT link_category_id  
        FROM res_partner_link_category
        WHERE (partner_id = %d);
        """ % (record.id,)
        cr.execute(sql_req0)
        sql_res0 = cr.dictfetchall()
        active_categories = []
        for rplc in sql_res0:
            sql_req1 = """
            SELECT id, type, date
            FROM   (SELECT id, type, date, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) AS rk
                    FROM res_partner_link_category
                    WHERE partner_id = %d AND link_category_id = %d AND date IS NOT NULL) as maximum
            WHERE  rk = 1;           
            """ % (record.id, rplc['link_category_id'])
            cr.execute(sql_req1)
            sql_res1 = cr.dictfetchone()
            if sql_res1:
                active_categories.append(sql_res1['id'])
            else:
                continue 
        result[record.id] = active_categories
    return result  # result is a dictionary whose keys are res.partner ids and values are lists of link.category ids
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could not show the button inside a many2many field, I am not sure if this is impossible from the OpenERP framework, but may be in these cases you have to use an icon instead of a class.

I did it this way, and at least the result is aceptable.

```
<button name="open_history" type="object" string="View history" icon="terp-calendar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check with what you have defined in "open_history". When I tested it with another function, am getting button in tree view with string "View History" displayed on that.

Comment: Ok, I am going to edit my post with the code of "open_history".

Comment: Before pasting here the code of the function, I checked what happened if I deleted its code and switch it to "pass". But the result is the same. Buttons are not being shown well.

Comment: I edited my post, I can only see the button out of the field "link_category", the problem is not the tree tag, I guess.